# Como migrar um site wordpress local para um servidor comercial?

Tags: wordpress

Eu fiz um projeto de um site (basicamente comprei um template e personalizei) em Wordpress localmente na minha máquina, agora preciso migrar esse projeto para um servidor comercial na web. Como faço isso sem precisar refazer tudo que já fiz?

Comment: basta transferir por ftp e mover o db tbm se você tivesse dado uma googada basica iria ver que o próprio codex do WP tem um tutorial super exato de como fazer isso. https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress